How to parse Program data in transaction logs
When check transaction log of https://solscan.io/tx/3TZeRWjoJ3W2tqTFB4QZRuwAEKCoYryCD2CLtwPXH4EdkaQHbpor7ndJ3FD9KYzb9ff66eKVRB1LeN4a9UzQVYRC
I see:
Program data: vdt/007mYe5w9oJ/ymPwCB2SVbwbi3Sh7teoss/Iny2fnDCAY8Wib0WBMgEAAAAADV+DeRgAAAABXWh7bP2lVlC8rCkbpqjZT2kSPgYp6BG/F/4b+yTjsERTl0FnAAAAAFSNYEMSAAAAiuA8pzx1AQBU4TxHCwAAAIpIKlurdgAA
How to parse this text to read infomation?
Thanks all.

Since program data is just a collection of bytes converted to base64, you'll need some sort of schema to interpret them. Unfortunately, the program that emit the log, 6EF8rrecthR5Dkzon8Nwu78hRvfCKubJ14M5uBEwF6P, doesn't seem to have any schema uploaded on-chain: https://explorer.solana.com/address/6EF8rrecthR5Dkzon8Nwu78hRvfCKubJ14M5uBEwF6P
If you research that address though, you'll see that it's the pump.fun program address. Here's a client-side library that might be able to interpret the logs: https://github.com/rckprtr/pumpdotfun-sdk, but I can't guarantee anything since I haven't used it.
